# casting of JSON to typeScript class in Angular2

Tags: angular

[image]

How to convert this JSON structure to Class

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`JSON2TS`](http://www.jsontots.com/)** which will automatically create a typescript class for you.

Just paste the JSON and see the corresponding ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, you can declare it by using this:

```js
declare module namespace {

    export interface Address {
        city?: any;
        area?: any;
        house_No?: any;
        landmark?: any;
        locality?: any;
    }

    export interface Order {
        product_Name: string;
        product_ID: string;
        order_Active: boolean;
        price: string;
        qty: string;
    }

    export interface OrderList {
        address: Address;
        order: Order[];
        order_ID: string;
        timeStamp: number;
        total_Amount: number;
        user_ID: string;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        orderList: OrderList[];
        orderSize: number;
        status_code: string;
        status_message: string;
    }

}
```